# Do the DLC boosters prevent trophies?

Tags: ruinverse

Ruinverse has 3 DLC packs that add boosters as follows:

- Damage x2
- Experience x3
- No skill cost

The descriptions say these boosters can be switched on/off in game.

Does enabling any of these boosters prevent trophies from being unlocked?